# event before submit in parsley.js

Tags: jquery, validation, parsley.js

I have some form and script for parsley:

```
<form id="myForm">
   <div id="overlay"></div>
   <input id='name' type='text' placeholder='enter name..'>
   <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    var myForm = $('#myForm');
    myForm.parsley();
</script>
```

Sometimes on my page another scripts add class 'active' to #overlay. This class depends on whether you need to validate the input. So, I need for some requirement, when I click on submit and before validating.
For example smth like this:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  if($('#overlay').hasClass('active))
    {$('#name').parsley()}
})
```

If #overlay has class 'active', then you need to validate input..
Help me )

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not as easy as it should.

If you are using a lightbox of some kind, ideally you would set `disable` on all your inputs, and set add `"[disable]"` to the `excluded` option.